# Nginx Ingress pass whole url to oauth proxy as Redirect

Tags: nginx, oauth, nginx-ingress

I am running a Kubernetes Cluster with an Nginx-ingress fronting couple of web apps. Because Nginx doesn't support SSO/OIDC by default, I use an oauth_proxy for authentication.

In detail I use oauth2_proxy (https://github.com/pusher/oauth2_proxy) with Azure AD.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-internal
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://example.com/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://example.com/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: "authorization, x-auth-request-user, x-auth-request-email, x_auth_request_access_token"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /home(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app-homepage-frontend-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /homepage-backend(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app-homepage-backend-service
          servicePort: 80
```

I skiped some details like tls. So in general everything is working, only verified users are able to access the web pages.

The issue is that my frontend is writte in Angular which use hash-routing. And if try to enter a deep route like

https://example.com/home/#/page1/subpage2

just base path (/home) is passed as redirect url. So when I'm authorized successfully, I get redirected to https://example.com/home.

Is there any veriable instead of $escaped_request_uri, which pass the whole url?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes and no. The issue is that everything behind the # will not passed to the server (and the redirect of the oauth proxy ignores that too). I fixed that by disable hash routing in angular. Without hash routing everything works like expected

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below process might be it will help!!

- Adding State Parameter will help for oauth2_proxy

**State Parameter**

State parameter will reserve the state prior to authentication request and pass random generated state value in request to authenticate and in call back request they will add state back i.e. Oauth2_Proxy generated id. Then Oauth2_Proxy will read that ID and provide the URL back and respond.

**Use below link**

https://dev.bitly.com/v4_documentation.html

**Bitly Oauth2_Proxy added the same in there code.**

https://github.com/bitly/oauth2_proxy/blob/master/providers/provider_default.go#L87-L89

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. But I need to know how I can get the scope from NGINX to pass it to oauth2_proxy.

Comment: Using above method you can share the state param. For sharing the state value you need to write nonce and provide the same nonce value while authenticating and after that once authentication completed redirect back with same state which you have shared then you can validate and fetch the value from save nonce. Nonce is like a generator which generate random value based on your input value(URL or something else) and store somewhere. Might be this link can help!!  https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/redirect-users