# Kubernetes - Ingress - Nginx : Forward query parameters from original request to auth-url

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Is there a way to forward query parameters from original request to auth-url? I know we have ***X-Original-URL*** but can we directly get them as query parameter for auth-url?

Answer (score 0):

Ingress controller cuts off url query parameters from the original request when calling external authorization endpoint.
This is an issue in `OAuth` scenario when the `OAuth` server sends the authorization code back to the resource server.
The auth enpoint needs that code to get access token.

Try to use the image `quay.io/aledbf/nginx-ingress-controller:0.185` it uses the `rd` parameter for the correct redirect url after the login.

You can also add **State Parameter**. It will help for `oauth2_proxy`.

State parameter will reserve the state prior to authentication request and pass random generated state value in request to authenticate and in call back request they will add state back i.e. `Oauth2_Proxy` generated id. Then `Oauth2_Proxy` will read that ID and provide the URL back and respond.

Take a look: [ingress-nginx-issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1113), [configuring-http-basic-authentication/](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/),  [url-to-oauth-proxy-as-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61342419/nginx-ingress-pass-whole-url-to-oauth-proxy-as-redirect).